# asp.net mvc Find Controller By Name With Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

My goal is to find a controller from it's name and area.  I have successfully done this if my current `httpContext` is within the same Area as the to-be-found controller.  However, I cannot get my call to the `ControllerFactory` to take Area into consideration.  Here's my code:

```
public static ControllerBase GetControllerByName(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controllerName)
    {
      IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
      IController controller = factory.CreateController(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, controllerName);
      if (controller == null)
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "The IControllerFactory '{0}' did not return a controller for the name '{1}'.", factory.GetType(), controllerName));
      }
      return (ControllerBase)controller;
    }
```

Since it's taking a `RequestContext` as a parameter, I've added an route value of "area" to it but with no change. Is there something I can do with the requestContext to some how take area into consideration? Do I need to override the controller factory--and if so, what in particular handles Area distinction?

Update:

Here is an example of a AreaRegistration I have:

```
public class StoresAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
  {
    public override string AreaName { get { return "Stores"; } }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
      context.MapRoute(
          AreaName,
          AreaName + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { area = AreaName, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried with `RequestContext.RouteData`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly, Yes -- `htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = areaName` and `htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["area"] = areaName;` were both tried with no success.

Comment: And how did you declare this route in your `Global.asax`?

Comment: Well the route is actually declared in the AreaRegistration.cs file. I've added it to the question.

Comment: You don't have access to the `Request.RequestContext` object in your `GetControllerByName()` function?

Comment: ? `htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext`

Comment: From inside your function `GetControllerByName()` you don't have access to the `Request` object?

Comment: If you get a chance, please mark the appropriate answer as accepted if it served your needs.

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution yet. I have the same issue and the answer below does not really look appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

The Area and Namespaces used to locate a controller are in the RouteData of the RequestContext. <s>They are populatd by default based off of the request you are currently serving up, if you need to change them you have to do so before calling CreateController.</s> You may get an exception when a controller cannot be found so you'll have to account for that as well.

**UPDATE**: Note, you MUST create a new RequestContext. If you reuse the existing one it will mess with the resolution of actions & views later on down the line in this request.

```
var tempRequestContext = new RequestContext(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext, new RouteData());
tempRequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Area"] = "";
tempRequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = "YourCompany.Controllers";
var controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory()
                .CreateController(tempRequestContext, "ControllerName");

if(controller != null)
{
    //TODO: Implement your logic here
}
```

Comment: Hi, slightly different error and this answer was what I was looking for although I have to changes ["Namespaces"] for ["namespaces"] (haven't used areas, so I don't know if that key requires lower case as well). Thanks

Comment: I use a capital in mine and it works fine, I'm not sure why you would have different results with a caps vs lowercase.

Comment: In MVC 5 apparently the Namespaces value expects an IEnumerable<string> instead of just a string. so use : `tempRequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new List<string> { "YourCompany.Controllers" };`

Comment: It should accept both. If you're only passing in only one namespace, you can just give it the string. You don't have to pass it in wrapped in a list. The type expected by `DataTokens["Namespaces"]` is of type `object`.