# Route with namespace and area still complaining about multiple controller names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, asp.net-mvc-routing, sitecore8

I have a folder structure for my Sitecore MVC project as such:

```
Areas
-- Common
   -- Controllers
      -- HeaderController
   -- Models
   -- Views
-- Legal
   -- Controllers
      -- HeaderController
   -- Models
   -- Views
```

I am trying to invoke a controller from code, and I am passing the `PageContent.Current.RequestContext`, and filling it with the appropriate namespaces and area.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Area))
            {
                PageContext.Current.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = this.Area;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AreaNameSpace))
            {
                PageContext.Current.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = this.AreaNameSpace;
            }
            return ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(PageContext.Current.RequestContext, this.ControllerName);
        }
```

But it still complains of the usual error:

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Header'.
```

I have the routes setup for each area, and the areas are all getting registered in the app_start in routeconfig.cs.

What could be the issue? Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to call a controller action from another controller class? or from a different class that is not a controller?

Comment: From a different class that is not a controller...

Comment: The `SitecoreControllerFactory` can't handle this. Actually, the only workaround is to rename the controllers to a different name. Another way would be to specify the controller full name in the Controller Rendering (with full namespace and assembly), but don't know if this will work in your specific case.

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl - This is for controller renderings, so it should just use the regular default MVC controller factory, no? I am using ControllerBuilder (from System.Web.Mvc) which I believe uses the DefaultControllerFactory, not the Sitecore one. I guess I 'can' provide the fully qualified name. I was thinking if I do that, its always instantiating by reflection, which may or may not be a performance issue. Since it takes in the Namespaces datatoken, I figured it can differentiate - but it doesn't - in the end, I may have to override the DefaultControllerFactory, but I was looking not to :(

Comment: @M.R. Sitecore sets it own ControllerFactory as default. I would specify the fullname in this specific case. We do this a lot in a recent project without any performance issues. It's also the recommended way from Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the solution is that in MVC 5 instead of use

```
PageContext.Current.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = this.AreaNameSpace;
```

you must define namespace as IEnumerable<string>

```
PageContext.Current.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new string[] { this.AreaNameSpace };
```

See [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83528/peter)'s commentary in [asp.net mvc Find Controller By Name With Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611652/asp-net-mvc-find-controller-by-name-with-area/15034456#comment46057714_15034456).

Answer (score -3):

You have to configure your default route as :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }, 
    new[]{"<namespace of you main controller (HeaderContriller)>"}                       
  );
```

You can refer my article here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/working-with-routes-in-mvc-framework/

Comment: You mean, I have to put the namespace in the default route? I already have it in the routes for the area...

Comment: can you share your route structure, area and main.